# How to know what the server returns too my application

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, server

I have the following web service.

```
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {  
const user = req.body;   

// registerSchema.validate(user, registerSchema, (err, result) => {
//     if (err)
//         res.status(500).end(err.message);
// });

findUserByEmail(user.email, (err, userFeedback) => {
    console.log('Fired.');
    if (userFeedback)
        res.status(500).end(JSON.stringify("User already exists"));
});

const passwordPromise = util.promisify(bcrypt.hashSync);
const pass = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password);

createUser(user.name, user.email, pass, [], (err) => {
    if (err)
        res.status(418).end(JSON.stringify("Failed to create user."));
});

res.status(200).end(JSON.stringify("Signup successful."));
});
```

with the following methods.

```
function createUser (userName, userEmail, userPass, dev, cb) {
var mg = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
mg.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, 
function(err, db){
    var dbo = db.db(myDB);
    var user = { name: userName, 
                 email: userEmail,
                 password: userPass,
                 devices: dev };

    var insert = util.promisify(dbo.collection("Users").insertOne);

    dbo.collection("Users").insertOne(user, function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`${user.name} has been added.`);
        db.close();
        sendEmail(userEmail, 
                  'The CRUST Company welcomes you!',
                  'Thank you for signing up for our services!' );
    });
});
}

//See if a user exists
function findUserByEmail (userEmail) {
var mg = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
mg.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, 
function(err, db){
    var dbo = db.db(myDB);
    var query = { email : userEmail };

    var find = util.promisify(dbo.collection("Users").find);
    return dbo.collection("Users").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        db.close();
    });
});
}
```

Then in my ionic app i have the following method that will register a user on our database through the web service

```
 register(postData: User): Observable<AuthResponse> {
return this.http.post<AuthResponse>(`https://1146c1fe.ngrok.io/register`,  (postData)).pipe(
  tap(response => console.log(response))
);
}
```

At the moment i can see what the server is returning to me but i am unsure on how to code responses to the response i get from the server. I would like the system to move on to a login page if the registration was a success, and if there was an error then the phone must display an error alert to the user,. How would one go about achieving this.

The user class looks like this

```
export class User {
name: string;
email: string;
password: string;
}
```

and i am unsure how I should make the AuthResponse class. It is currently empty

Comment: I am currently working on fixing the callback methods within the web service

Answer (score 0):

You can check the status of the response returned from the server. Your server returns "Signup successful." message with code 200 on successful registration. You can code the following logic:

- If server returns code 200, then the ionic application should navigate to Login page
- If the response status is not 200, then you should show an alert dialog that displays the error message returned from the server.

Comment: How would i go about putting that logic into javascript? Sorry this is my first time working in javascript, if i have an example i can reverse engineer it to work out how this is done but I am unsure on how the response will be received by my system.

Comment: Can you see the response in the browser's console when you run your application with this code ?  return this.http.post<AuthResponse>(`https://1146c1fe.ngrok.io/register`,  (postData)).pipe(
  tap(response => console.log(response))